# Change order of JavaScript files in head

Tags: magento2, layout, javascript, requirejs

I add a custom JavaScript file with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="VendorNamespace_Module::someJs.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

My problem is that this js file requires `jQuery`, but it is loaded before the `jQuery` JavaScript file (when I look at the head section of my html, `jQuery.js` comes after `someJs.js`). How can I change this order so that my file is loaded afterwards?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to change the order. you just have to declare that your script depends on jquery.
Make your `someJs.js` file look like this

```
define([
    'jquery'
    //you can add here any other dependencies you have
], function($) {
    ...your file content here
});
```

**[EDIT]**
If the js is from an source you cannot modify, like a third party module you can just create your own module that contains a js file with this content

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'VendorNamespace_Module/someJs'
]);
```

then include that file in the layout instead of  `VendorNamespace_Module/someJs.js`.
This should load jquery before the vendor js.

But on the side note...if you got a third party module that has a js file that does not start with `require` or `define` then it might be something wrong with the module.

Comment: What if this file comes from some module that is a composer dependency and I can not edit it? Or what would be if it comes from some external resource?

Comment: you got me here. I don't know yet how to do this. If I find something I will let you know.

Comment: Thank you. If you take a look at rearrange elements in this docs: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_css
maybe it is possible to get this working with the `move`? But I don't know if there are containers for that.

Comment: See my edit. Maybe it helps.

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for, but seems to be a safe workaround for me.

Comment: I have a script that is interfering with

Comment: OK, but what if it's loading your script before require.js?