# How to load js file first in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs, requirejs-config.js

I'm using Magento 2 and I have a js file that was called like this:

**default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
      <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
          <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Ajax\Login\Js" template="Vendor_Module::login-ajax.phtml" name="login.ajax" as="login.ajax" before="head.components" ifconfig="loginpopup/general/enabled" />
      </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**login-ajax.phtml**

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "vm/loginajax"    : <?php echo $block->getJsOptions(); ?>
    }
}
```

**requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'vm/loginajax': 'Vendor_Module/js/login-ajax'
        }
    }
};
```

**Vendor_Module/js/login-ajax**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/translate',
    'jquery/ui',
    'mage/validation/validation',
    'vm/mycustom'
], function ($, $t)
```

the js file size is 3KB , i noticed the js file is rendered not at the very beginning, how can i set the priority so this js file will load first?

Comment: check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48167553/magento-2-add-custom-script-just-after-head-tag

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102347/change-order-of-javascript-files-in-head

Answer (score 2):

You cannot manually manage the sort order of JS files within core Magento 2 to the level you are asking for, and even if you could you do not want your file to load first as you have dependencies:

```
'jquery',
'mage/translate',
'jquery/ui',
'mage/validation/validation',
'vm/mycustom'
```

You **have** to wait until your dependencies have loaded else you will just run into a lot of errors. If for some reason you really do want your file to load first then do not use Require JS at all.

Comment: Totally right 

Comment: Ben is right here. Question is what do you want to achieve? I mean not what you want to do on code level but what you want to do in you store from user perspective? Perhaps there is some other way. However looking at the name of js script and the list of dependencies I guess it will be difficult to make it in different way.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to load this js file first then instead of added after body, you can added then into head section like this.

**default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
      <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
          <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Ajax\Login\Js" template="Vendor_Module::login-ajax.phtml" name="login.ajax" as="login.ajax" before="-" ifconfig="loginpopup/general/enabled" />
      </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: is not this still inside the <body> tag?

Comment: Do you want this in body tag or head tag?

Comment: i want this js file should be loaded up first, should not be matter in head or body

Comment: Then you can use above code.

Answer (score 0):

Add your `login-ajax` JS file in the **default.xml** file of your custom module `Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
    <link src="Vendor_Module::js/login-ajax.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Keep the file `login-ajax.js` at `Vendor\Module\view\frontend\web\js\login-ajax.js`

And finally,

Run `setup:upgrade and setup:static-content:deploy` commands.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Need to override `root.phtml` instead of using `require.js`.

Copy default `root.phtml` from `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/base/templates/` to your theme location `app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/Magento_Theme/templates/`.

Edit the file to include your script right before or after where `require.js` is included.

```
<!doctype html>
<html <?= /* @noEscape */ $htmlAttributes ?>>
    <head <?= /* @noEscape */ $headAttributes ?>>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/your/custom.js"></script>
        <?= /* @noEscape */ $requireJs ?>
        <?= /* @noEscape */ $headContent ?>
        <?= /* @noEscape */ $headAdditional ?>
    </head>
    <body data-container="body"
          data-mage-init='{"loaderAjax": {}, "loader": { "icon": "<?= /* @noEscape */ $loaderIcon ?>"}}'
        <?= /* @noEscape */ $bodyAttributes ?>>
        <?= /* @noEscape */ $layoutContent ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this error as `require` is not yet defined?

Comment: Above solution will load JS file at the top where code should be written without any dependency(core JS).
Using RequireJS as you've mentioned we cannot manually manage the sort order of JS because RequireJS loads its module source files asynchronously, and doesn't promise anything about the order they're loaded in.
Just we can manage "load order" dependencies using RequireJS shim configuration directive.

Comment: Ah I see, yeah that would work but not in this use case as there is a dependency on jQuery, jQuery UI, Magento's core validation, and translations :(